# Permissions on an ext4 filesystem on a removable drive used in different machines

Tags: permissions, files, ext4, removable-storage

I have a USB flash drive with `ext4` file system and its files are owned by my user on my local machine, for example by `myuser@myhost` with `700` permissions.

If I unplug my flash drive and plug it in other Linux machine, can users of that machine have access to files in the flash drive?
What if there is also a user named `myuser`, can he access those files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filesystems designed for unix, such as ext4, track the user via a number, the user ID. The user name is not recorded. You can see your own user ID with the command `id -u`. You can see the user ID who owns a file with `ls -ln /path/to/file`.

If you take an ext4 filesystem to a different machine, the files will still have the same permissions, and they will have the same user ID. This may or may not be the right user. In general, different machines don't have the same user IDs for the same users unless this requirement was taken into account when creating the user or the machines pool from the same user database.

Permissions on a file only protect that file inside one system. Permissions on a removable drive have no effect for someone who pops the drive into their own computer.

If you want to exchange files via USB, FAT32 is usually the filesystem of choice. It's what most flash drives are formatted for when they're sold. If you need to store files with names or attributes that FAT32 doesn't support, create an archive (e.g. `.tar.gz`).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, on the other system if you have a user with same user ID then he/she will have access to it.

Comment: Make this clear though: "user ID" in unix means the *numeric* uid assigned in `/etc/passwd`, not the name. "myuser" is not a user ID. If the names and numbers don't match up the same way on both machines, it's the number that decides which user gets the permission.